# Vagrant - Reaching your django server from host machine

Tags: python, django, vagrant

I setup a vagrant VM using `puphpet` configurator, I installed a number of programming languages including PHP, python, ruby etc. I installed `apache2` and `mysql` for PHP projects but its `django` that I really need to get up and running. Heres the part of the config file where the network IP and hostname are defined:

```
            machines:
                vflm_zpwmfbk4aw05:
                    id: machine1
                    hostname: machine1.puphpet
                    network:
                        private_network: 192.168.56.101
                        forwarded_port:
                            vflmnfp_pjysbxl944a0:
                                host: '9346'
                                guest: '22'
                    memory: '2000'
                    cpus: '1'
```

When I `vagrant up` then point my hosts browser to `192.168.56.101` I get a blank screen. Which means its connecting to something, otherwise I'd get a 404 screen.

I read that to access the django server from your host, you need to run this:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

But when I point my browser to `192.168.56.101:8000`, I get the 404 screen.

Heres whats in the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       machine1.puphpet        machine1
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       vagrant.vm      vagrant
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.3.3     myhost.dev
```

I manually added the last line `192.168.3.3     myhost.dev` because I decided to change the settings that were installed by default but it doesn't work.

Heres the interfaces file:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
pre-up sleep 2
#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
      address 192.168.56.101
      netmask 255.255.255.0
#VAGRANT-END
```

Could apache2 be conflicting with djangos server? Is there a way to find out exactly what IPs and ports are available from the VM?

Comment: If you're not exactly sure what you're doing, always follow this steps : First, make sure it works in your VM - start django and connect to it (using wget or curl) to make sure you can access it locally. Second fix the network issue with your host, you cant add the IP and name you want in your host file it must be the IP of the VM with the hostname of your VM in your case '192.168.56.101' and 'machine1.puphpet' if you want to change those values you must change in your config yaml file

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Its all about port forwarding. This VM I had setup had bad port forwarding setup:

[image]

The host port is 7280 and the guest port is 22. This means I would have to run the VMs django server on port 22, and point the hosts browser to port 7280. This doesn't work because port 22 is reserved so I can't run the django server on it. The solution is to add an additional port forwarding rule. 8000 works fine. So setting both the guest and host ports to 8000, I can run the server on port 8000, then access it through the host at port 8000.